# How to merge two fields of a SQL query into a single one with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

With a PostgreSQL environment, I have following tables:

```
\d tx_out
                                        Table "public.tx_out"
       Column        |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |              Default
---------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id                  | bigint            |           | not null | nextval('tx_out_id_seq'::regclass)
 tx_id               | bigint            |           | not null |
 index               | txindex           |           | not null |
 address             | character varying |           | not null |
 address_raw         | bytea             |           | not null |
 address_has_script  | boolean           |           | not null |
 payment_cred        | hash28type        |           |          |
 stake_address_id    | bigint            |           |          |
 value               | lovelace          |           | not null |
 data_hash           | hash32type        |           |          |
 inline_datum_id     | bigint            |           |          |
 reference_script_id | bigint            |           |          |

\d tx_in
                               Table "public.tx_in"
    Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id           | bigint  |           | not null | nextval('tx_in_id_seq'::regclass)
 tx_in_id     | bigint  |           | not null |
 tx_out_id    | bigint  |           | not null |
 tx_out_index | txindex |           | not null |
 redeemer_id  | bigint  |           |          |
```

and I have following query:

```
SELECT tx_id, tx_in_id FROM tx_out
LEFT JOIN tx_in ON tx_out_id = tx_id AND tx_out_index = index
WHERE address = ANY($1)
```

where

1. `tx_id` and `tx_in_id` are of the same type
2. `tx_id` can have repetitions
3. `tx_in_id` can have repetitions
4. `tx_in_id` can be `NULL` (from the `LEFT JOIN`)
5. values of `tx_in_id` can be repeatd in `tx_id` (and obviously vice versa)

and I need to get distict values from `tx_id` and `tx_in_id`.

I can do:

```
WITH source AS (
  SELECT tx_id, tx_in_id FROM tx_out
  LEFT JOIN tx_in ON tx_out_id = tx_id AND tx_out_index = index
  WHERE address = ANY($1)
),
combined AS (
  SELECT tx_id AS id FROM source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tx_in_id AS id FROM source WHERE tx_in_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM combined ORDER BY id;
```

but this means to repeat the complex query twice :(

Is there a more optimized way to get the same result?

Thank you

Comment: _repeat the complex query twice_, do you mean typing or executing?

Comment: Why not use UNION instead of UNION ALL and not remove outer query since union only returns distinct values

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)